# Does this actually return the total return of a portfolio?

Tags: r, finance, quantmod, stock, performanceanalytics

I've ran into a bit of trouble of late trying to calculate the returns of my investment portfolio. Here's one way which has been recommended on the Rstudio blog.

This way uses the `Return.portfolio` function from `PerformanceAnalytics` and which shows the 'dollar growth' of a portfolio. If anyone has experience with this I'd be keen to hear your thoughts on whether or not this is an accurate method.

```
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
library(quantmod)
library(dygraphs)

symbols <- c("GOOG", "AMZN", "BA", "FB", "AAPL")
stock.weights <- c(.15, .20, .25, .225, .175)
getSymbols(symbols,  src = 'google', from="2017-01-01")
#merge closing together
port.closing <- merge.xts(GOOG[,4], AMZN[,4], BA[,4], FB[,4], AAPL[,4])
#change closings to returns
port.return <- na.omit(Return.calculate(port.closing))
#portfolio returns with wealth.index = TRUE to apply to $1 invested - no rebalance
port.norebal = Return.portfolio(port.return,
    weights = stock.weights, wealth.index = TRUE)
#visualise dollar growth
dygraph(port.norebal)
#calculating return on portfolio taking the current date and dividing it by investment date
PortfolioReturn <- as.numeric(tail(port.norebal,1)) / as.numeric(head(port.norebal, 1))
PortfolioReturn
```

So, I've got the growth of $1 of my portfolio as calculated by the `Return.portfolio` function and I calculate the percentage increase between the current date and the investment date. Does this accurately show the capital growth of the portfolio?

Answer (score 0):

Not quite:  when you do `Return.portfolio` starting on 2017-01-03, it gives you an index where the value at 2017-01-03 is assumed to be a 1.  But it doesn't actually include the 1 at 2017-01-03 in the series.

The portfolio return is `as.numeric(tail(port.norebal,1))`.  When you divide by `as.numeric(head(port.norebal, 1))`, you're getting the return since the second day of the portfolio (not since the first day).  i.e. you're dropping the returns from 2017-01-04 from your calculation.

Also, don't forget to subtract 1 in your return calculation.  Your portfolio return 40%, not 140%.

To help wrap my head around the problem, I computed an equal-weighted version of your portfolio by replacing your `stock.weights` line with

```
stock.weights <- rep(0.2, 5)
```

Then I calculated the returns from first principles:

```
end.price = port.closing["2017-09-13"] 
start.price = port.closing["2017-01-03"] 
mean(as.numeric(end.price) / as.numeric(start.price) - 1)
```

This gives me 0.382475, which is equal to `as.numeric(tail(port.norebal,1)) - 1`.